# HTML Menu Bar in one page to include in other pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, menubar

I'm on writing a homepage in HTML, CSS and JavaScript and have a question about making of a menubar.
I've already a design and put it on every site that I have but I also thought about how complicated t would be to change a little thing in it. So I tried to make one site which only shows the menubar and then link it in the beginning of every page. That would allow me to minimize the effort to change things in the menubar. But I'm a very beginner so I didn't failed completely. 

It would be nice if somebody can help me. I'm German and not very good in speaking or writing English so I'm sorry about the mistakes I probably made.

The code i use if you maybe need it:

```css
 ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
    }

    li {
        float: left;
    }

    li a, .dropbtn {
        display: inline-block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        background-color: red;
    }

    li.dropdown {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Startseite</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="keywords" content="Startseite">
        <meta name="description" content="Meine Startseite">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <ul id="fixed">
      <li><a href="menu.html">Startseite</a></li>
      <li><a href="timetable.html">Stundenplan</a></li>
      <li><a href="report.html">BOGY-Bericht</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Javascript</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="js1.html">Beispiele 1</a>
          <a href="js2.html">Beispiele 2</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="animation.html">Animationen</a></li>
      <li><a href="canvas.html">Bouncing Ball</a></li>
      <li><a href="links.html">Verweise</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You can use a little php with it and make an `header.php` and `footer.php` then require them in your pages. Like : `<?php require header.php ?> your html code <?php require footer.php ?>` I will make an plunker for you.

Comment: html only allow you to use embed codes to import pages in each other's which is not best solution in your case, i go with SupremeDEV answer and suggest you using php files and including them to your page.
`ps` don't panic when we say php, is just your file format, content are just your nav html codes. no php code needed.

Comment: Also, if you use `Ruby on Rails`, you can create a partial like `_header.html.erb`, and then render it in `application.html.rb` like this: `<%= 
render 'header' %>`

Answer (score 0):

```html
You have to make a new folder for include in which common data should be placed (header.php and footer.php)
Name of first File - index.php -
<?php include('include/header.php'); ?>
```

```html
Name of the second file - header.php(contains Common data (menu bar) )
header.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>Startseite</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <meta name="keywords" content="Startseite">
            <meta name="description" content="Meine Startseite">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        </head>
 <body>
   <ul id="fixed">
          <li><a href="menu.html">Startseite</a></li>
          <li><a href="timetable.html">Stundenplan</a></li>
          <li><a href="report.html">BOGY-Bericht</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Javascript</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="js1.html">Beispiele 1</a>
              <a href="js2.html">Beispiele 2</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li><a href="animation.html">Animationen</a></li>
          <li><a href="canvas.html">Bouncing Ball</a></li>
          <li><a href="links.html">Verweise</a></li>
            </ul>
```

```html
Name of third file is footer.php
      
    Footer.php
        </body>
        </html>
```

Files should be saved with the php extension

You have to use this include file in every individual page

```html
 <?php include('include/header.php'); ?>
```

add include file on every individual page 
[image]

Comment: That looks pretty nice, but it seem to doesn't work for me. I copyed all of what you said, but if I run the file, there's nothing. Also tried a tutorial to include and it happened the same

Comment: Then please check the file name or is the extension of the file is correct

Comment: Please make a new folder of include in the main folder and place the header.php,footer.php,main.php file

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/4tM3AuE i have the folders like this and in the files copied what you wrote and https://imgur.com/a/FEDyKPh this is what is showed to me -.-

Comment: Why body tag and head tag is showing on the top of the include tag

Comment: keep head section on the other file as main .php

Comment: because my name is in the meta author tag and i doesn't wanted to show it.. the rest is the normal html construction. but thank you, you really try to help a noob as I am :)

Comment: https://imgur.com/1xp1yqT is this how the include should looks like? because if i try this, firefox tries to open or save the file and not handle is as a webpage

Comment: Yes its correct, Now do 1 thing keep you code from <html><body> in header.php file

Comment: and in footer.php  </body></html>

Comment: https://imgur.com/de2nQ6l i've done it, but: https://imgur.com/a/Gca2RUJ you see what happens

Comment: Have you placed menu.php outside the include folder?

Answer (score 0):

This can be your `header.php`

```
<html>
     <body>
           <header>Hello World</header>
           <div>
```

This can be your `footer.php`

```
           </div>
           <footer>Bye World</footer>
     </body>
</html>
```

And this may be your other page example: `other.php`

```
<?php include ('header.php'); ?>
My html here.
<?php include ('footer.php'); ?>
```

Try it out, I hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: All what it shows is "My html here.". The text which is written in footer.php und header.php isn't there

Comment: @Trauma are the `header.php` and `footer.php` in the same map as `other.php` ? If not you should link them right. Otherwise try to place them in same map. I have tested the code and it works for me as it should.

Comment: @Trauma are you running it on some localhost server? Such as. xampp, usbwebserver, wamp etc. Note that php has to be run on any apache server .

Comment: i just do "open with firefox" and that's what it shows. i'd try it with the internet explorer too but i don't think that it would make any difference

Comment: in internet explorer it tries to download the file other.php like in the other answer below

Comment: Okey so first install any apache server on your computer. For begginer i recommend using USBWebserver or Xampp. After installing it make a map in the `htdocs` map in the installed program(xampp or any) files. Start your program and apache server. Then go to localhost/yourmap/ in your browser.

Comment: I'l try this at home, because I'm on the computer of the company where I do my internship at

Comment: @Trauma Okey. I hope to hear your reponse if everything went fine :) Good luck !